# update using a subquery causing error

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

What is wrong with below query, I'm trying to update a count in daily table using a weekly one , I've to update a count per item in daily table using the count for same item in weekly

```
  select  a.ik , a.date , d.count
  from Table1 a , Table2 b ,
  ( select count from Table2 b
   where b.ik = a.ik and wk in 
   ( select wk from calendar_table c,Table1  where c.calendar_date = Table1.date)) as d
```

table 1

```
    ik,           , date
    133;0;"002996";"2014-06-26"
     11;0;"003406";"2014-06-22"
```

table 2

```
     ik, wk , count
     368;201605;0
     377;201438;0
```

calendar_table

```
   date, wk
   "2013-08-15";201329
    "2019-09-05";201932
```

Comment: I'm getting this error after executing it ''subquery in FROM may not refer to other relations of same query level''

Comment: Can you show us some piece of data that is in each table (just some few lines of each table)?

Comment: There is no `update` in your question. `count` is a reserved word, it's a bad idea to use it as a column name. You need `select "count" ..` in your sub-query. And finally you are not joining those two tables and the sub-query so that generates cross product of all those three tables - that's almost always an error as well

Comment: I'm going to create a table with this select and update one column in another table later on....

Comment: So which table should be updated? `table1` or `table2`?

Comment: I'm updating table1 with the count from this query

Answer (score 1):

```
select  a.ik , a.date , b.count
  from Table1 a
  join Table2 b on b.ik=a.ik
  join Calendar_table c on c.calendar_date=a.date
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update table1, something like this should do it:

```
update table1
  set "count" = t.cnt
from (
  select t2.ik, c.date, t2."count" as cnt
  from table2 t2
    join calendar_table c on c.wk = t2.wk
) t
where table1.ik = t.ik;
```

With your sample data this won't update anything because there is no `wk` in `table2` that matches the `wk` values in `calendar_table`

Comment: this won't work because it will update the table1 (which is on daily level) with only values matching for a single date for that week , I want to replicate the weekly value(count) for all 7 dates for that week , per item in the daily table....thanks!

Comment: @puzeledbysql: then your sample data doesn't make sense (at least to me)